# How to access build id in CircleCI task

Tags: sed, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am trying to run a `sed` command to replace an environment variable indicating the current build id. According to the documentation [CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/) contains the value I'm looking for, and according to [this example](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#example-configuration-of-environment-variables) it should be super easy to use in a `command`.

Below is the config file, below that the `bundle.gradle` file the `sed` command is being executed on, and below that is the result. As you can see the `sed` command simply treates `CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM` as a string vs grabbing the build number.

**config.yml**

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
android: circleci/android@0.2.0

jobs:
build:
  executor: android/android

  steps:
    - checkout
    - setup_remote_docker: 
        docker_layer_caching: true      
    - run:
        name: testing env vars
        command: sed 's/${BUILD_NUM_1}/${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}/g' -i build.gradle
```

**bundle.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
def buildNum = ${BUILD_NUM_1}
```

**output**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
def buildNum = ${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}
```

Comment: Double quote the `sed` substitution -> `sed "s/${BUILD_NUM_1}/${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}/g"`

Comment: @Inian doing that caused the job to blow up with the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

Comment: Which means, your `${BUILD_NUM_1}` variable is not set, at the time the command runs. Try running this on your terminal `echo foobar| sed 's//bar/'`

Comment: @Inian thanks, the issue was specifying `${BUILD_NUM}` as an env var.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sed` command worked.

```
 - run:
     name: testing env vars
     command: sed "s/_buildNum/${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}/g" -i build.gradle
```